# How to share VPN established in VMware guest VM with host

Tags: windows, ubuntu, virtual-machine, vmware-workstation

Is there a way to share a VPN connection which is established in a VMware guest running Windows 7 with the host running Ubuntu 14.04?

I tried NAT and Bridge, but I cannot seem to access VPN endpoints in the browser from the host OS. This is only available from the guest OS.

Comment: Is the Guest OS getting it's internet from the host, or from a passed through networking device (eg: wifi usb stick)? You will need to setup I.C.S. (Internet Connection Sharing) in Windows 7, and then either configure the host to get it's internet from the VMware network adapter, or if no passthrough was used, you'll need to configure host firewall rules to force certain applications to use the vmware adapter while allowing the host to still access the regular internet connection to be able to provide to the vm. I suck at I.C.S. so I can't provide an answer, but it can be done.

Comment: Alternatively if proxy level protection would be enough for your purposes you could just setup WAMP on your Windows guest, dump PHProxy into the www folder, and then open the host web browser pointed at your guest vm's ip (use NAT for ease).